# I want to split up the Strings in StringBuilder?

Tags: android, string, listview, stringbuilder

I have a ListView that shows each item as so:

Animal - Colour - Number

---

Animal - Colour - Number

---

Animal - Colour - Number

---

I have put these Strings in a StringBuilder so it displays on each item of the ListView. When I click the ListView item to go onto the new activity, I want it to display the results of the String 'Number'. However, the results only display on the new activity when the Animal and Colour strings are commented out/deleted. I understand that I have to split the strings into three separate Strings but all the tutorials I am following don't seem to work.

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks.

```
 try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Search");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject result = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(result.getString("Animal"));
            sb.append(" - ");
            sb.append(result.getString("Colour"));
            sb.append(" - ");
            sb.append(result.getString("Number"));
            results.add(sb.toString());
```

Comment: do you want to split Animal - Colour - Number to Animal, Colour and Number?

Comment: i would like each string to be separated from each other so that only the number value is read by the next page. at the moment its reading the entire string for some reason and not displaying any results. if that's what you mean by animal, colour and number then yes

Answer (score 1):

To split the String you have to use String's split method

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("Animal - Colour - Number");
String[] strings = stringBuilder.toString().split(" - ");
```

Now strings[0] is Animal, strings[1] is Color and strings[2] is Number

Comment: thank you for ur response. i tried this method and unfortunately it didnt work

Comment: on your code you append the strings. I want the code where you tried to split them

Comment: between the last two lines, i inserted String[] strings = sb.toString().split(" - ");

Comment: in your code you are getting the values from the json and then I suppose you add them on your ListView. You have to make the split when you click the item from the ListView. On the click you have to get the item's text and then split it.

Comment: do u suggest i do it in the new activity that opens up or do i stay in this activity?

Comment: please post the code with your list's item click listener to explain you

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.print("Tiger - Red - 10".split(" - ")[2]);
```

Will print `10`.

Comment: will this work for my code above where i used an array adapter?

Comment: also what is the meaning of the number 2

Comment: I suggest you to start with some book about java firstly, before jumping in Android